# FindByValue of DropDownList always returns null in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

The ASP.Net DropDownList's `FindByValue` method always returns null when it is bound to a SqlDataSource control.

But, if the DropDownList bound to a DataTable, FindByValue is working as expected.

Comment: Please show your code here so that we can figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that FindByValue() is called after data-binding in the first case?

Comment: OR the only reason of getting null is that there might be some issue with DataBinding and value you are finding is not existing in the DropDownList.

Comment: Check if the binding is done correctly. Also check what values are getting populated on the form in Dropdown items value property because FindByValue uses the Value of the items to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the source of the problem, I posted above, and the solution,

The DropDownList was inside a panel that was initially hidden, so the DropDownList didnot get bound to the SqlDataSource when the `FindByValue` is executed in a Button Click Event.

I solved the problem by forcing DropDownList to bind to the DataSource using `DataBound()` of
DropDownList in the Page_Load Event Handler.